# Can I change the project key format at all in JIRA without breaking JIRA Agile?

Tags: jira, jira-agile

We require the ability to use numbers in our JIRA project keys.

However looking at the documentation it says that any change to the default project key format should be avoided as Greenhopper only supports the default (at least two upper case letters).

http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA044/Configuring+Project+Keys

All I want to do is allow numbers and not any other characters like dots or dashes which are more likely to break Greenhopper so I was wondering if anyone has changed the key format to use numbers (maybe something like ([A-Z][A-Z0-9]+)) and not had an issues with Greenhopper?

Comment: So why not just trying it out? Make a backup, install a development server, and do it :-)

Comment: I was thinking of doing that but was a little reluctant in case it caused some subtle problem that wasn't immediately apparent. I may have to give it a go though.

Comment: @Mike - how did you get on with this? The key problem we find with JIRA project keys containing numbers is that the quick search (top right) does not work if you enter an issue ref (e.g. A123BCD-100 will generate a smart query (incorrectly) instead of recognising it as a valid issue key) - in Jira 4.4, not yet updated to 5.

Comment: Never found the time to try it to be honest. Thanks for the tip on the quick search as that's something we use a lot for the smart queries.

Comment: I'm running JIRA 5.1. I just changed my projectkey pattern to ([A-Z][A-Z0-9]+) and created a project with a key of SP7. The quick search functionality seems to work fine with issue numbers like SP7-1, etc. (I don't know about Greenhopper, however).